# Automatically apply default bootstrap-daterangepicker filter to a DataTable when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have followed some posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702675/datatable-filtering-by-date-range-not-returning-correct-results) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993211/selecting-this-month-range-by-default-in-bootstrap-daterangepicker/40993901#40993901), in order to make my default `startDate` and `endDate` (or for example, "This month", like on the second link) from bootstrap daterangepicker be applied to my DataTable when the page is loaded but I am new to JavaScript and I can't make it work.

To be clear, I need to set a default date on daterangepicker, and this default date must be used to filter the results from my DataTable **when the page is loaded**, before the user has had any interactions with the page.

Once the page is loaded, the user can then choose a different date range and re-apply the filter as they like.

I think I just have to find a way to make the JSFIDDLE from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704273/5420229) work together with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993901/5420229).
I've also asked this question [on the daterangepicker repository](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/1348), but no luck so far.

Can anybody help me with the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to the question I asked, but since I couldn't make it work using the tools I had in mind, I decided to change to the [Bootstrap table plugin](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/custom-toolbar.html).
It works perfectly for what I wanted. Bear in mind that this code only works when you are getting the data from the server. It does not work if you want to only filter the data on your browser.
My coded ended up like this (make sure to set the default value for the `start_date` and `end_date` fields):

HTML:

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <div class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>Start date: </span>
            <input name="start_date" class="form-control w70 datepicker" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span>End date: </span>
            <input name="end_date" class="form-control w70 datepicker" type="text">
        </div>
        <button id="ok" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
<table id="table"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-height="800"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-query-params="queryParams"
       data-response-handler="responseHandler"
       data-url="path/to/data" <!-- exemple: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/filter-data/" -->
       data-row-style="rowStyle"
       class="table-condensed">
       <thead>
       ...
       </thead>

       <tbody>
       ...
       </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $table = $('#table');
$table.bootstrapTable(
    {
        'pageSize': 30,
        'pageList': [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }
);


var $table_lancamento = $('#table'),
    $ok = $('#ok');
$(function () {
    $ok.click(function () {
        $table_lancamento.bootstrapTable('refresh');
    });
});
function queryParams() {
    var params = {};
    $('#toolbar').find('input[name]').each(function () {
        params[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    return params;
}
function responseHandler(res) {
    return res.rows;
}
```

Your `filter-data` function in the backend MUST return a json in the following format (example from the link provided):

```
{
  "total": 800,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Item 0",
      "price": "$0"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "price": "$1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Item 2",
      "price": "$2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Item 3",
      "price": "$3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Item 4",
      "price": "$4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Keep an eye on your browser console and network tabs to keep track of what is going on.